# Auto populate of column on the visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I designed a VF page to display a list of field records of a custom object. There are two number fields in my object I designed VF page to display these number fields with total at the bottom of the page . In future if an additional number field is add to same object then how can I write a code to add a column which in turn should be automatically populate on the visualforce page. Is it possible in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a controller / controller extension on this page you could use describe calls to learn the list of all fields in the object, check their types and decide which ones you want to display & summarize.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Account.NumberOfEmployees.getDescribe();
System.assertEquals(Schema.DisplayType.INTEGER, f.getType());
```

But relying on results of a describe call will have some limitations (hitting governor limit of 100 describes per request, fields will be sorted by name which might not be the order you want to display them...).

Since you want dynamic Visualforce you could consider making a [fieldset](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) or custom setting that would list the fields you want and then if you're using Apex to calculate subtotals - [refer to it from code](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm). That way when you need to update it later you won't have to touch the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Please find some code below. Note, this is not tested but shall give you a complete idea!**

```
VF Page:
<apex:form>
      <!-- this column will return the sum -->
      <apex:column value="{!Sum}"/>
</apex:form>

Apex Class:
//Your class will contain the below method
    public String getSum(){
             Double Sum;
            //Return a list of the object
            List <Custom_Object__c> listCustom = [Select Num1, Num2 from Custom_Object__c];
            for(Custom_Object__c co : listCustom){
                Sum = co.Num1 + co.Num2;
              }
             return String.valueOf(Sum);
    }
```

**The answer will be something along these lines. Please give it a try, if it does not work reply and I shall be happy to help!**